# Como iniciar o chrome em uma versão específica com o selenium em python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome

Fiz um script que utiliza o Selenium para automatizar umas páginas web e ele é utilizado por algumas pessoas. Porém, hoje ele não funcionou porque o chromedriver estava numa versão inferior ao navegador Chrome, que sofreu uma atualização. Minha dúvida é: eu consigo iniciar o Chrome com uma versão específica? No caso, com a mesma versão do chromedriver? É inviável ter que ficar atualizando sempre a versão chromedriver pra ficar igual com o Chrome de todos que utilizam o programa.
Obrigado!

EDIT:

Deu certo com a resposta do amigo lmonferrari, mas precisei fazer uns ajustes pois também uso o `webdriver.Chrome(options = option)` e ele não aceitou outro argumento. Pesquisei e achei como solução usar o `Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())` armazenado em uma variável e depois colocar como argumento no `webdriver.Chrome()`. Fiz o seguinte:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service   

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()) #só precisa fazer o que está nessa linha e depois colocar a variável como argumento service                    
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()                                                 
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {                                  
    "download.prompt_for_download": True})                   
with webdriver.Chrome(service = s, options=option) as driver:
    #seu código aqui
```

obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o: [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/).
Ele verifica a versão do seu chrome e faz o download do driver.

Para instalar basta utilizar o pip: `pip install webdriver-manager`.

Exemplo de uso:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```